# Prove that a complicated parametric equation is a portion of a circle

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

In a nuthshell, I would like to prove that some complicated parametric equation is that of a portion of a circle.

Let $ P =  \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}X \\Y \\Z \end{array} \right] $
be a 3D point lying on a line $L$, passing through $\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}a \\b \\c \end{array} \right] $ and directed by vector $ \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}u \\v \\w \end{array} \right] $.

We can write P in parametric form, using $t \in \mathbb{R}$:

$P(t) = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}X(t)\\Y(t) \\Z(t)\end{array} \right] = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}a + ut\\b + vt \\c + wt\end{array} \right] $

$P(t)$ is then projected on $\mathbb{R}^2$, giving point $p(t)$, through the following equation:

$$ p(t) = 2\tan\left(\frac{1}{2}\arccos\left(\frac{Z(t)}{\sqrt{X(t)^2+Y(t)^2+Z(t)^2}}\right)\right) \left[\begin{array}{ccc}\frac{X(t)}{\sqrt{X(t)^2+Y(t)^2}}\\\frac{Y(t)}{\sqrt{X(t)^2+Y(t)^2}}\end{array} \right]$$

I would like to show that $p(t)$ describes a portion of a circle, and find said circle's center and radius as a function of the parameters of the line $ \left(a, b, c, u, v, w\right)$.

I made [an illustration to conjecture that this is true on Geogebra](http://dchiffresdnotes.fr/circle_demo.ggb).

I have tried to find the center and radius of the center using three known points on this circle (for $t=0$, $t=+\infty$, and $t=-\infty$), but I end up with very complicated and untractable computations. I'm pretty sure there is an easier way, but I can't find it.

Thank you in advance for your help :)

Comment: It _might_ help if you eliminate that trig stuff. If $v=2\tan(\frac{1}{2}\cos^{-1}(\frac{p}{q}))$ then $(\frac{v}{2})^2=\frac{q-p}{q+p}$